# how to insert uniqueid generated with uniqid()); function into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing this application to take input from users and insert it into **MySQL** database.
I am able to insert what the user `key` into the **textbox** into the database and i have used the PHP function `uniqid()` to generate unique id and populate the `id` into a **textbox** like this:

```
<input type="text" readonly name="caseid" 
        value="<?php printf("CASE-%s\r\n", uniqid());?>"/>
```

but the issue is when i used the the PHP function `$i = $_POST['caseid']` to insert it into the database it does not insert the data into the database, not the `id` but also all data in the **textbox**. I am using the the above process for date function

```
<input type="hidden" name="systemdate" 
        value="<?php echo date("d-M-Y h:i:s"); ?>">
```

to insert system date automatically.

Please help me out here Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just make your table to have an Auto increment `id` column ?

Comment: Please also note that uniqid is a bit of a misnomer as it does not guarantee a unique ID. Please check to PHP documentation ( http://php.net/uniqid )

Comment: ok thanks man but i have the auto increment but this id is very important for me